# How do I get my child theme in wordpress to work with multiple style sheets?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I have `styles.css`, `footer.php`, `header.php`, and `functions.php` in my child theme folder. (`wp-content/themes/kingdom-child`) This site is composed of woocommerce and bootstrap files.  I have this in my `functions.php` file :

```
<?php
function enqueue_child_theme_styles() {
     wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style', get_stylesheet_uri(), array('kingdom-style') );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_child_theme_styles', PHP_INT_MAX);
```

I have this in my styles.css file:

```
/*
Theme Name: Kingdom - Woocommerce Amazon Affiliates Theme
Theme URI: http//smarttvsandgadgets.com/
Description: Kingdom - Woocommerce Amazon Affiliates Child Theme
Author: Charlie Aubuchon
Template: kingdom
Version: 1.4
*/

/* =Theme customization starts here
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
```

`header.php` and `footer.php` are untouched.

I tried making some styles to alter the theme and it didn't do anything.

What am I doing wrong? (not much knowledge of php, found all examples on the web.)

Comment: What is `PHP_INT_MAX` for? That can go...

Comment: it's a default PHP constant used as priority param

Comment: I know what it is...I just don't understand why it would need to be there. By default, a child theme will enqueue its styles after a parent theme.

Comment: @futureone, not sure if it's a typo, but it should be `style.css` instead of `styles.css`

Comment: Yes, sorry. it is style.css

Answer (score 0):

In Documentation some examples were for older WP. I have updated the minute stuffs. Theme Handbook has older reference, because people left project and same people actually continued to code for main WP development. Two years old story. Essentially WordPress.ORG is a voluntary project. There can be minute differences among docs. But OP had actually a basic question. It has been made complicated.

**If OP needs only customization, learning enqueue is not needed for basic usage**.

Preferably, keep a backup copy of the `style.css`. Edit in proper editor like vi or gedit for the sake of syntax highlighting. Open style.css in text editor. Do not use WP's function. If you edit in MS WordPad, I do not what can happen.

If modification does not work, it can mean many things like the Cached page is loading, user agent is respecting some other directive, OS + Browser combination is bad and so on. Use a developer tool to debug on Chrome or Firefox with empty cache, cookies. Using the WP Editor can fail for browser caching. Cache plugins should be off. Edit on a dev server. Ensure these points first. Then remove this `, PHP_INT_MAX` part and try.

How bootstrap is compiled that can matter.

**More for the OP**

> footer.php, header.php, and functions.php in my child theme folder.

Yes, never touch that `functions.php` file without backup. Whenever we'll say you to add this snippet to `functions.php`, unless otherwise mentioned, it is that file. Without it, child theme will not work. `footer.php` and `header.php` are not mandatory files. We usually override default functions with these files. If `home.php` or `front-page.php` is present, that will override your settings from WordPress Admin for homepage.

I've nothing to do with 00M or that paid theme. You at this level need not to know about PHP. May be other stylesheets are loading - check the resources with webpagetest.org. It is likely that you are editing a file that actually is not what you need to edit. Use developer tool. Without touching PHP (except removing that `, PHP_INT_MAX` - note the comma, it should be removed too) you can customize.

**Other unnecessary topics came via the answer**

Without the comments, this is exactly the right for newest version of WP :

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_child_theme_styles', PHP_INT_MAX);
function enqueue_child_theme_styles() {
wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri().'/style.css' );
wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style', get_stylesheet_uri(), array('parent-style')  );
}
... other stuffs ...
```

Result will look like importing CSS.

I have no idea about M00. I guess OP added `<?php` opening here, it has more stuffs above the lines. It is normal to have some comments on the file's starting.

This will be right way via a Plugin like Header and Footer Plugin, as pure HTML :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://42.akamai.net/stackoverflow.com/questions/d.css" media="all" />
<!-- media="value", value = all, print, ... 
 Old reference from w3c 
 http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#adef-rel 
 Microsoft Windozzz IE [1 to 8] can fail to fetch huge number of resources. 
 Conditional IE specific CSS might be needed.
-->
```

We often deregister materials and serve in this consistent way. Reverse functions. For own website we need the absolute URL, for developmental purpose the PHP functions are used. **These are for additional stylesheets not for basic customization but optimization**.

`PHP_INT_MAX` in `add_action()` points to the fact that the developer wanted the parent stylesheet to appear after all the other stylesheets has been loaded. OP can remove it to test. It is not possible to say whether the usage is wrong unless we can see the whole `functions.php`.

There are number of ways to print the path or uri because we do not know what is the website's FQDN :

```
get_template_directory_uri()
get_stylesheet_directory_uri()
get_stylesheet_uri()
get_theme_root_uri()
get_theme_root()
get_theme_roots()
get_stylesheet_directory()
get_template_directory()
```

I have not understood why suddenly the person referenced WP enqueue script function and wrongly cited [my webpage](https://thecustomizewindows.com/2014/04/advantages-disadvantages-wp-enqueue-script-function/]) and Net [Tut+ guide](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/the-ins-and-outs-of-the-enqueue-script-for-wordpress-themes-and-plugins--wp-22509). They are for different purposes. Not for child theme's stylesheet customization. StackoverFlow has a value. I, at least never say to do a wrong cocktail of PHP and HTML! One can have different opinion but **I never said to not use WP enqueue script for the child theme's main stylesheet**. If you have any question, before putting the link, you could ask us. That was for non-blocking Java scripts and have `async`, `defer`. I respect your learning and helping, but possibly you should review your answer and correct the syntax.

We were talking about other things, that person has misunderstood. Here is child theme's reference :

`codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes`

Again, I have nothing to do with OOM or that child theme. I came here by searching domain name to disavow. I gave the links and the solution. Thats how people starts using WordPress. After 5 years, if you continue tweak, you'll become micro-guru for maintaining your own websites.

Sorry for the bigger reply.

Answer (score -2):

According to your question, Two choices (my answer is no good)

**If** (for beginners only need stylesheet to work only as the fastest way)

Say you just want stylesheet to work only, why not use normal external css include way. and view source see if your css link is working and in the right loading position (is found instead of 404).

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/style.css">

// previsouly got confused about the following 4 wp functions: 
get_stylesheet_directory(): file path to current Theme directory
get_stylesheet_directory_uri(): url path to current Theme directory
get_template_directory(): file path to parent Theme directory
get_template_directory_uri(): url path to parent Theme directory
```

I personally do not follow wordpress template's default function way to add css, js. sometimes i do not care much about the benefit of enqueue (I admit it's wrong):     https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/49098/what-are-the-benefits-of-using-wp-enqueue-script

But I might just put it anywhere that is best for me to read  or to Do overriding,control load order etc , in testing phase as my personal preference.

**else,**  ( there are many benefits using enqueue scripts)
    you take a bit more time debug it in understanding how the template load script and thier sequence, neglect the above hard-code script answer.

TWO more reference link on enqueue script;

**The ins and outs of the enqueue script for wordpress**

ttp://code.tutsplus.com/articles/the-ins-and-outs-of-the-enqueue-script-for-wordpress-themes-and-plugins--wp-22509

**The advantages and disadvantages wp-enqueue-script function**
  ttps://thecustomizewindows.com/2014/04/advantages-disadvantages-wp-enqueue-script-function/

As I'm also low reputation user as the author,I would like to lend a helping hand using the limited knowledge i've researched and learned. while we are participating the discussion , providing related answers/references to such question, **there are always many ppl who prefers to downvote to remove answers while there is actually no better answer comming  yet** or correcting the information refered. Such deed is not a good culture of discussion.

Comment: I downvoted this for a few reasons. (1) `get_template_directory_uri()` returns the PARENT theme directory, not the child theme...this just won't work; (2) syntax errors in your markup; (3) this is the wrong way to enqueue things.

Comment: actually get_template_directory_uri is the normal way to get a dyn wordpress template url then use the right "/custompath" behind can get the  correct url already, in those child theme templates  usually they have defined their own CONSTENT VARIABLES i didn't remember , CHERRY or other frameworks may use different names.

Comment: No. This is wrong. Read [the documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory_uri). And I quote: `In the event a child theme is being used, the parent theme directory URI will be returned, get_template_directory_uri() should be used for resources that are not intended to be included in a child theme.`

Comment: yup i think i'm not correct.thanks pointing out. @rnevius  get_stylesheet_directory_uri() is recommended.

Comment: So, should I have get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); in fuctions.php to replace get_stylesheet_uri();  .. ??

Comment: actually, @futureone  , you are a 1 point user, and as you mentioned as a beginer not knowing much php, you do not even have enough reputation to vote yet, my answer is trying to provide as detail information as possible for a beginner to choose, don't kown why stackoverflow these ppl so like downvote post and wanted it to be removed.  If you also think unuseful, i may just delete this post soon.